# How to use "eval" in R to assign variable names in a list?

Tags: r, list, character, eval

I'm trying to dynamically create elements in a list, where each element in the list is actually a list of values.  For the sake of isolating the problem, `i=3` is used here, but `i` can really be any integer or any character/string.

```
i=3
varname = paste("x", as.character(i), sep="")
X=list()
var = rnorm(10, 100, 5)
new_list=list(eval(varname)=var)
```

The above gives the error traceback:

```
3: var = rnorm(10, 100, 5)
4: new_list=list(eval(varname)=
```

But now check this out:

```
# but "eval(varname)" is a character
print(eval(varname))
```

[1] "x3"

```
# and this works:
new_list=list("x3"=var)
```

...so, why doesn't the line `new_list=list(eval(varname)=var)` work?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to name the elements with `setNames`

```
new_list <- setNames(list(var), varname)
```

Comment: This works.  But why DOESN'T the way I'm trying this work?  Please help me understand the nuances of R a little more deeply.

Comment: The reason your code does not work is because `eval(varname)` will not be evaluated. It is on the left-hand side of the equals sign within a call. It is a special position that requires a straightforward name. Use akrun's suggestion.